# Eliminate the gap at the end of a range of values in Highchart Bulletchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bullet-chart

I want to show the last plot band value(225) as the max value in x axis.In the picture you can see the x axis max value is 300, that's why a gap is created. I want to show the plotband
max value 225 as the max value in x axis. So the gap will eliminate.
[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
chart: {
    marginTop: 20,
    width: 225,
    height: 80
},
title: {
    text: ''
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['<span class="hc-cat-title">Revenue</span><br/>']
},
yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
        from: 0,
        to: 132,
        color: '#666'
    }, {
        from: 132,
        to: 157.7,
        color: '#999'
    }, {
        from: 157.7,
        to: 225,
        color: '#bbb'
    }],
    title: null
},
series: [{
    data: [{
        y: 225,
        target: 157.7
    }]
}],
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<b>{point.y}</b> (with target at {point.target})'
}
```

});

Jsfiddle: [Bullet Chart](https://jsfiddle.net/shantosiddiq/9jsx8azc/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `max` property and disable the `endOnTick` option:

```
yAxis: {
    ...,
    max: 225,
    endOnTick: false
},
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/je7ocpnh/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.endOnTick

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek but 225 doesn't show as label in the axis.. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Hi @Shanto Siddiq, You can use `tickPositions` or `tickPositioner` properties: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hLpzyucd/

Comment: Can u please help me with showing the tickmarks with the value to the graph?

Comment: Hi @Shanto Siddiq, Sure, you need to increase the `tickWidth` property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7c280b5k/